# SVG circle stroke opacity

Tags: svg, fill, stroke

Is it possible to make the circle's stroke opacity, and not having that inner circle?
Like this:

[image]

I can only do like this so far:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" style="
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: purple;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
    fill: green;
"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use `paint-order:stroke fill; ` for the circle mining that the svg will paint first the stroke and next the fill. You may need to also change the stroke width and the radius od the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `paint-order: stroke;` property to the circle's style declaration. You may also need to change the stroke width and radius of the circle.

```css
@namespace svg url("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
/* Important so that we don't end up targeting HTML elements */

svg {
  width: 200px;
}

svg|circle.example-circle {
  fill: #008000;
  stroke: #800080;
  stroke-width: 15px;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="35" class="example-circle" />
</svg>
```